# Unable to reinstall ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 in dual boot.

Suddenly there was a problem and I was unable to boot into any of them (both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10). So I reinstalled Windows 10 and then I tried to reinstall Ubuntu. However, while I was reinstalling Ubuntu:

1. I selected something else
2. I deleted the existing Ubuntu 14.04 partition by selecting it and clicking `-`.
3. It showed free space but when I selected it for installation it again shows Ubuntu 14.04 (name of the disk)
4. I stopped the installation

My grub menu still shows up old Ubuntu. So how do I install Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, deleting a partition doesn't actually destroy filesystem data; it just deletes the *pointers* to the data. (Partition table data consists mostly of pointers to where filesystems start and stop.) Thus, when you deleted a partition and re-created it in exactly the same way, the original filesystem data became available again.

Instead of trying to delete and re-create the partition, you should be able to use the "Something Else" screens to re-install over the existing system. Be sure to select the check box to "format" the Ubuntu root (`/`) filesystem. This will quickly delete all the important filesystem data structures. Alternatively, you could use GParted or text-mode tools like `mkfs` to wipe the original Ubuntu 14.04 partition before launching Ubiquity (the Ubuntu installer). You'd need to boot into the installation medium's "try before installing" mode or use some other emergency tool in order to do this, though.

As a side note, I recommend taking this opportunity to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04. Although 14.04 is still supported, it's over halfway through its supported period; it will enter unsupported status in less than two years. Ubuntu 16.04 also offers a number of updates and improvements over 14.04.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the old Ubuntu 14.04 partition and extend the Windows 10 one using GParted (from the Ubuntu Live CD Session). Then double-click on the "Install Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS" icon and follow the instructions.

*(Remember to select dual-boot with Windows 10 and to resize the partitions.)*

Comment: This would probably work, but adds needless risk. Partition resizing operations carry a certain amount of risk, and this process does it twice -- once in GParted, to increase the size of the NTFS partition, and again in Ubiquity, when you tell it to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Comment: @RodSmith I did the same about 3 times on my Dell OptiPlex PC with Ubuntu 10.10 and Ubuntu 14.04 and there wasn't any problem. I do not know about your hard disk's condition, but I really hope this will work. You also have a Windows 10 installation disc just in case...

Comment: I'm not the OP. Doing something three times without problems does not mean that it's risk-free. There could still be a 10% chance of failure on any one attempt and doing it three times would mean about a 73% chance of success at all three operations. (That's pulling a failure rate out of thin air. I doubt if the failure rate is as high as 10% on an individual partition-resizing operation, but it's certainly higher than *not* doing such an operation.) Why take the chance when a safer and faster alternative is available?